# Using indexOf with an Angular variable

Tags: angularjs, indexof

I have the following expression in my code:

`({{article.lawyers.indexOf(sortAtt)}})`

where `article.lawyers` is [1] and `sortAtt` (defined by a dropdown on the page) is 1 and I'm getting a -1 for the above expression.

I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious since it's late and I'm tired, but could someone please help me figure out why this isn't working? I'm using it in a sort filter that filters articles by (among other things) whether or not the chosen lawyer is in the array residing in article.lawyers.

If I hardcode a "1" instead of `sortAtt`, it works, so I'm thinking it's some sort of binding issue.

Thanks!

EDIT to add more code:
I'm not sure how to do a JSFiddle for this since there's too much else behind it, but hopefully this code will help:

```
  <form>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search News Articles" ng-model="searchNews" size="70">
<br/><br/>
Find a year's articles: &nbsp;
<select ng-model="sortYear">
<option ng-click="sortYear='all';">All Years</option>
<option ng-repeat="article in news | orderObjectBy:'year':true | unique: 'year'" ng-click="sortYear={{article.year}};">{{article.year}}</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
Find articles related to a specific attorney: &nbsp;<br/>
<select ng-model="sortAtt">
<option selected value="">All Attorneys</option>
<option ng-repeat="lawyer in attorneys| orderObjectBy:'lastname':false" value="{{lawyer.id}}" ng-click="sortAtt={{lawyer.id}};">{{lawyer.firstname}} {{lawyer.lastname}}</option>
</select>
</form>

</div>

<div id="news-titles">
    <div ng-show="sortYear=='all'">
        <div ng-bind-html="sortYear">All Articles</div><br/>
        <div ng-repeat="article in news | filter: article.lawyers.indexOf(sortAtt) > -1 | filter:searchNews">
                <h3 ng-bind-html="renderHtml(article.title)" ng-if="article.lawyers.indexOf(sortAtt) > -1"></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="sortYear!='all'">
        <div ng-bind-html="sortYear">{{sortYear}} Articles</div><br/>
        <div ng-repeat="article in news | filter: article.lawyers.indexOf(sortAtt) > -1 | filter: {year: sortYear} | filter:searchNews">
                <a href="" ng-click="loadNewsArticle(article.article);">{{article.title}}</a><br/><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there maybe a different way to run that filter? article.lawyers is an array of IDs. I just want to make sure that the selected ID (if there's one selected) is in that list before displaying the article.

Comment: If you put some JSFiddle code, it would help to identify your problem

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use the filter than using business logic in view level. And this will solve your problem as well.

```
yourModule.filter('indexFilter',function(){
  return function(arr,val){
    return arr.indexOf(val)>-1;
  }
});
```

You can use it in your code as

```
<div ng-repeat="article in news | indexFilter: article.lawyers:sortAtt | filter: {year: sortYear} | filter:searchNews">
                <a href="" ng-click="loadNewsArticle(article.article);">{{article.title}}</a><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: I was trying along those lines, but wasn't writing it correctly, I don't think. I tried your version and no links show up, whether or not I've selected an attorney.

Comment: Here's the fiddle of the code, but, like I said before, there's a whole lotta JSON data behind it, so this doesn't have data in it since I don't want to replicate all that.  https://jsfiddle.net/exh0aLy7/

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I alert "val"in the filter, it says ärticle.lawyers, not the value of sortAtt